# Setting cameraViewTransform dynamically for iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working on a camera app where I am supposed to show a camera inside [image]

I am using `camView.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0) ;` but getting different results for different devices and a black bar in between tab bar and camera. If I change the value of `scaling` the camera is too zoomed up. Any help in this matter would be very appreciated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self prepareCamera];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:NO];
    [self launchCamera];
}

- (void)prepareCamera{
    camView = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    camView.delegate = self;
    camView.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    camView.showsCameraControls = NO;
    [self resizeCameraView];
}


- (void)resizeCameraView{
    CGSize screenSize = self.view.bounds.size;
    // set the aspect ratio of the camera
    float heightRatio = 4.0f / 3.0f;
    // calculate the height of the camera based on the screen width
    float cameraHeight = screenSize.width * heightRatio;
    // calculate the ratio that the camera height needs to be scaled by
    float scale = screenSize.height / cameraHeight;
    // move the controller to the center of the screen
    camView.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, (screenSize.height - cameraHeight) / 2.0);
    // concatenate the scale transform
    camView.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(camView.cameraViewTransform, scale, scale);
}

- (void)launchCamera{
        [camSubView addSubview:camView.view];
        [camView viewWillAppear:YES];
        [camView viewDidAppear:YES];
}
```

Comment: could you post some code how do you set up the camView view?

Comment: @Istvan thanks for looking up, I have updated source code.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to achive is not supported officially by Apple. From the [UIImagePickerController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/):

> To use an image picker controller containing its default controls, perform these steps:
>
> ...
>
> 4. Present the user interface. **On iPhone or iPod touch, do this modally (full-screen) by calling the `presentViewController:animated:completion:`** method of the currently active view controller, passing your configured image picker controller as the new view controller.
>
>    On iPad, if you specify a source type of UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera, you can present the image picker **modally (full-screen) or by using a popover**. However, Apple recommends that you **present the camera interface only full-screen**.

What you can do is to present the UIImagePickerController modally (full-screen) and add custom controls with the [`cameraOverlayView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView) property.

**Solution**

To achieve what you want you have to use AVFoundation and not UIImagePickerController. AV Foundation library offers a much more powerful way of taking photos, which lets you put the camera view inside your own app. You can find a good tutorial [here](http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/), or a newer one [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/camera-capture-on-ios/#overview)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look into the matter. If what you are saying is true then how come the CamFind application has implemented UIImagePickerController in side tab bar. Here is the screen shot of the app and from what I can understand by running their app is the camera is not presented modally, please correct me if I am wrong. Here is the screen shot https://www.dropbox.com/s/7vyixgo6f0pg64f/CF-iPhone6.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Most likely they are using AVFoundation to take pictures and not UIImagePickerController. AV Foundation library offers a much more powerful way of taking photos, which lets you put the camera view inside your own app. You can find a good tutorial here: http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/

Answer (score 1):

The question is what you want to have in a result. CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0) is default scale - so this isn't make any changes. 
The camera on the all apple devices have aspect ratio 4:3. Also, I must admit that default camera view have size which equal screen width with height thats leads the promotion 4:3 - thats why you have always different camera view.

If you want have camera view with height that equal the screen heigh you need make some affine transformation. Here is an example :

```
CGFloat cameraAspectRation = 4.0/3.0;
CGFloat cameraViewStarterHeight = screenSize.width*cameraAspectRation;
CGFloat cameraAdjustedYPosition = (screenSize.height - cameraViewStarterHeight)/2 - 20;
CGFloat cameraScaleTransformCoef = screenSize.height/cameraViewStarterHeight;

CGAffineTransform adjustedYPositionTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, cameraAdjustedYPosition);
CGAffineTransform adjustedScaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(cameraScaleTransformCoef, cameraScaleTransformCoef);

self.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(adjustedYPositionTransform, adjustedScaleTransform);
```

But in this way, as you saw camera view will be "zoomed".
Hope this will help you to understand the problem you have.

Comment: Thanks, but your code is resulting in following for iPhone 6 https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8pgu07v97qm3mg/iPhone-6.png?dl=0 and iPhone 6 Plus https://www.dropbox.com/s/ajy6vodoryccd7r/iPhone-6Plus.png?dl=0 its working fine for iPhone 5

Comment: @DeepeshGairola Just remove "-20" and it will be  fine for iPhone6 and 6+. I've done that because I have no status bar on my controller where I use this.

Comment: @DeepeshGairola I mean for iPhone 6 and 6+ use CGFloat cameraAdjustedYPosition = (screenSize.height - cameraViewStarterHeight)/2